# react typescript what type is setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am passing a setState as a prop from a parent component to modify the state on a child component of that parent, on typescript when creating a interface, what is the type of setState?

```
function App() {
    const [links, setLinks] = useState();

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <Sidebar setLinks={setLinks} />
            <Main />
        </div>
    );
}
```

on child:

```
interface SidebarProps {
    setLinks: ??????;
}


const Sidebar: React.FC<SidebarProps> = ({ setLinks }) => {
    return (
        <div style={sidebar}>
            <button onClick={() => setLinks('1')}>pic1</button>
            <button onClick={() => setLinks('1')}>pic2</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: appears to be a `(link: string) => void;`

Comment: worth pointing out that in your interface and the `App` component you've called it `setLinks`, but in the `Sidebar` you're using `setLink`

Comment: yeah that was my bad, i didnt double check before send. I set (links: string) => void; but still throwing error: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<undefined>>' is not assignable to type '(links: string) => void'.

Comment: That tells you the type right there, `Dispatch<SetStateAction<undefined>>`, which `Dispatch` and `SetStateAction` can be imported from `react`

Comment: "which can be imported from react" thats what was missing.

Answer (score 6):

This is my example based on Kyrill's answer.

```
interface Props {
  editMode: boolean
  setEditMode: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

export default function NavToolbar(props: Props): ReactElement {
 
...
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this though :)

Answer (score 2):

Refer the below code:-

```
function App() {
    const [links, setLinks] = useState<string>();

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <Sidebar setLinks={setLinks} />
            <Main />
        </div>
    );
}


interface SidebarProps {
    setLinks: Function;
}


const Sidebar: React.FC<SidebarProps> = ({ setLinks }) => {
    return (
        <div style={sidebar}>
            <button onClick={() => setLinks('1')}>pic1</button>
            <button onClick={() => setLinks('1')}>pic2</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: isnt it more genetic to say it is a function only?

Comment: yeah setLinks is a function.

Answer (score 1):

React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction>

Above `string` can be replaced if you infer a type for setState (e.g. I assumed `setState<string>()`)